# Is there some built in, or otherwise available, syntactic sugar, for create-on-access (private) properties in C# (.net 4.5)?

Tags: c#, singleton, .net-4.5

I'm looking to implement a private singleton, and create it on access in C#. Is there some syntactic sugar or well known blurb of code for this pattern?

---

The best ways i know of doing this, involve wrapping the "SomeSortOfSingleton" inside of a (nested) class, or, as mentioned in the comments, by using the `Lazy<T>`.

Both of those are quite cumbersome - multiple lines of code, using anonymous functions, and lead to having two fields on my class - one implementing the singleton, and the other referencing it.

IE, neither of those methods qualify as **syntactic sugar**.

This is a fairly common pattern, so either there must be some sort of built in sugar for it, or *someone* must have implemented a sugar for this

(ie, for a non-platform defined bit of sugar, it might look like this:

I'm looking to write something like this (or just as short and hard to get wrong):

```
public class SomeClass
{
   [Lazy]
   [Singleton]
   private static readonly SomeSortOfSingleton;
}
```

)

Comment: [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C# by Jon Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx)

Comment: Maybe you could provide the code that you're thinking of? I think this is not a really good question although you have a lot of reputation...

Answer (score 1):

If single threaded guaranteed

```
private T _t = null;
public T Instance
{
  get
  {
    if (_t == null) {_t = new T();}
    return _t;
  }
}
```

If MT possible

```
private readonly object _tSync = new object();
private T _t = null;
public T Instance
{
  get
  {
    if (_t == null)
    {
      lock(_tsync)
      {
        if (_t == null)  // Second check b/c another thread may've gotten the lock while we were waiting.
        {
          _t = new T();
        }
      }
    }
    return _t;
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm looking for syntactic sugar. i'll update the question title